# Problem in making white space between two apended inputs and adding the scrollbar for when the allocated space is filled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add "white space" between  $("#signEmail").val() and loggedInUserInput.val()

Where signEmail is the username which the user used to login, its saved in the localstorage
Where loggedinuserinput is basically the value of the inputbox
They are both appended into a devcontainer called main-Comment-Container-One

The function is working fine but i need to make a space between them for readability
The second problem is if I comment many times, my comments go through the comments container through the body, I need to know how to add scroll down effect.

```js
const commentMainVideoButtonOne = $('#comment-Main-Video-Button-One');
const loggedInUserInput = $('#comment-Main-Video-One');

$('#comment-Main-Video-Button-One').on('click', function() {
  $('.main-Comment-Container-One').append($("#signEmail").val(), ":     ", loggedInUserInput.val(), ("<br />"));
});
```

```css
.iAmTheCommentMaster {
  height: 1024px;
  width: 1024px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.main-Comment-Container-One {
  /* border-top: 2px solid rgb(19, 145, 255); */
  border: 2px solid rgb(19, 145, 255);
  border-bottom: transparent;
  background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
  height: 600px;
  width: 880px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#comment-Main-Video-One {
  /* input box*/
  height: 60px;
  width: 790px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-color: #1391ff;
  border-right: transparent;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#comment-Main-Video-One:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

#comment-Main-Video-Button-One {
  height: 34px;
  width: 87px;
  background: #1391ff;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #111;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iAmTheCommentMaster">
  <!--body which text is appened to-->
  <div class="main-Comment-Container-One"></div>
  <!--comment text box-->
  <input id="comment-Main-Video-One" placeholder="Enter text here">
  <!--input text box-->
  <button type="button" id="comment-Main-Video-Button-One">comment</button>
  <!--comment button-->
</div>
```

Comment: There's no `signEmail` in your HTML.

Comment: The signEmail is taken from localstorage

output currently looking like this:
xxx@hotmail.com:test
I need it to be like this:
xxx@hotmail.com:  test

Comment: If it comes from localStorage, why are you using `$("#signEmail").val()`?

Comment: I dont think it matters for now to be honest since its able to get the the email

Comment: Your code does put whitespace after the `:`. However, you won't get 4 spaces because the default is to merge whitespace into a single space. You can use the `white-space: pre;` style in the DIV, or you can use `&nbsp;` characters instead of spaces.

Comment: Genius! Thank you again and again Barmar, you have been very helpful throughout my learning process!